# Visual studio C compiler not linking header file to its source counterpart

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, header, linker

I am using VS and playing around with my first chunk of reusable code in C, so I've separated my code into header files and source files, and that has cause some unexpected behaviour.
It seems to me that somehow, the linker can't resolve my typedefed structs. I've tried moving the actual struct declarations into the implementation file, and typedefing the structs from the header file, but without success.
For the sake of brevity, I removed all the implementation, as that is not the problem.

```
// queue.h
#ifndef INC_QUEUE_
#define INC_QUEUE_

#include <stdint.h>

// STRUCT TYPEDEF
typedef struct QueueElement { ... } QueueElement;
typedef struct Queue { ... } Queue;

// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
Queue* queue_construct();
uint32_t queue_peek(Queue *);
void queue_enqueue(Queue *, uint32_t);
uint32_t queue_dequeue(Queue *);
uint8_t queue_empty(Queue *);
void queue_destroy(Queue *);

#endif
```

```
// queue.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

Queue* queue_construct() { ... }
uint32_t queue_peek(Queue *queue) { ... }
void queue_enqueue(Queue *queue, uint32_t element) { ... }
uint32_t queue_dequeue(Queue *queue) { ... }
uint8_t queue_empty(Queue *queue) { ... }
void queue_destroy(Queue *queue) { ... }
```

The source code is all fine, it all compiles, but when I attempt to include this in e.g. this file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main()
{
  Queue *q = queue_construct();
  queue_destroy(q);
  return 1;
}
```

The error my linker is persistently giving me:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct Queue * __cdecl queue_construct(void)" (?queue_construct@@YAPAUQueue@@XZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl queue_destroy(struct Queue *)" (?queue_destroy@@YAXPAUQueue@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is probably a silly question, but as I have said, I've never tackled a "larger/multifile" project in VS C.

**EDIT**
It has been pointed out to me that the source file that contained the main function was indeed inside a cpp source file, but my header and implementations were inside C files. To the best of my knowledge, you can use C files anywhere inside your C++ code, an example of that is the ability to use any C system libraries inside C++.

The program now works fine, but now my question is: why can't I use a C header inside a cpp file? Why is this the case here. Clearly I am missing something important.

Comment: It looks like functions from queue.c cannot be found. Are you sure that this file is part of your project and is built together with main.c?

Comment: I would say so. I've got a project with the default folders that VS creates for a given C++ project, my *.h files are in the "Header files" folder, and the source files are in the "Source files" folder.

Comment: The only thing that I see is that the struct name and the typedef are the same.  Try changing `typedef struct Queue { .... } Queue;` to `typedef struct queue_ { ....} Queue;`  I find it hard to believe that this would be the cause, but it is the only thing that I can see.  This is assuming that both main.c and queue.c are being compiled and linked together.  N.B.  Way back in the last century (circa 1983) when I was learning C someone told me to insure that the names were different...can't remember the explanation, I just always did it.

Comment: the reason names should be different is due (back when) to only one namespace inside the compiler.  Modern compilers are much better at tracking different associations with the same name spelling.   However, struct definitions should have a tag name and no typedef name.  then all references to the struct definition should be 'struct tagName.'   using the struct tagName helps in several areas:  code is clearer/not cluttered with unnecessary/misleading names, the compiler name space is not cluttered with superfluous entries and it is the preferred syntax

Comment: it looks like the queue files were compiled under C and the main file was compiled under C++

Comment: Thank you for you input, I did try changing the struct definitions before, but had found that that was not the problem. But thank you for clearing up why it is good to use the struct notation in certain cases.
The problem was that my main file was indeed a cpp file, as was pointed out, but the queue was written in c. I was not aware that I could not use C source and header files in a cpp file, I thought that that was possible, as all C libraries are available in C++. If anyone knows why that is not the case here, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of some comments, the problem was that my main program was written within a cpp file, and was including my own c header files. To my foolishness, I was unaware that you can not simply use C libraries inside C++.

Simple converting the main file into a C source file fixed the problem.

This was not what I needed, as I needed my source files to be in C++ so one search away, and the solution was simple. I merely needed to change my main cpp source file like so:

```
// main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
  #include "queue.h"
}

int main()
{
  Queue *q = queue_construct();
  queue_destroy(q);
  return 1;
}
```

Hopefully this keeps somebody else from making the same naive mistake I made.